# a href not woriking with img?

Tags: html, css

i have code

```
<div><a href="example.php"><img ...></a></div>
```

Img has width 100%. I tried `a {display: block}` But it didnt help. I think that **img** override **a**. How to solve this problem?

Comment: can you please show us more detailed code? also if possible please provide the link to the site

Comment: i think that i show enough. if i do padding inside a, then i can see that link work         ` img{
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
}`

Comment: The code you share must work because there is nothing wrong with it.  I think no one could reproduce your problem.

Comment: that's not enough. basically it should work without doing anything but since there is problem in your code, I need to investigate it, what the problem is looking the whole code

Comment: ok. if it must work then maybe i have a lot of jquery code and something cancel this action.

Comment: yes, i really had jquery code with img click. this code overrides action.

Comment: check this :  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_image

Comment: i checked, it works. now i know that it works) i updated my jquery code with img click which overrided this action.

Answer (score 0):

With the height of the image and width 100%, the image now acts as the link object, a click on it should take you to your link.

I try Your scenario in one of my page and i notice that some part of my image(in my case, from the top to about 70px down) didn't work as link area(a mouse-over at that area reveals a pointer cursor).I don't know why but it appears as if there is a div that was overlapping at the background with the div tag in which the img tag was in.I advise you to check in your case if that's the case.